# как проверить хранится ли в базе данных MySQL слово, которое было введено в программе JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

В общем есть БД слов, где каждому слову присвоена цифра.

(CУБД MySQL. База данных mybase. Таблица new_table. Слова в столбце word, цифры в столбце tonality.)

БД была подключена к IntelliJ IDEA с помощью DB Browser. 
Пользователь вводит слово и если такое слово есть в БД нужно вывести это слово(word) и соответствующую ему цифру(tonality)

Вопрос: как это прописать в коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаете, как запрос составить, или не знаете, как отправить запрос с помощью java?

Comment: второй вариант...

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/database/2.1.php